# Know what you're selling on PayPal?

Tags: php, paypal

I would like to add the option to buy items from my website (written in PHP) and I thought the best way to do it was to integrate PayPal's developer tools in my website.

Given that the items for sale are unique, I need to act when an item is sold, e.g., stop displaying the "Add to Cart" button. Consequently, I set up an Instant Payment Notification (IPN) listener, following the [example](https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4) PayPal provides. In its current implementation, the listener sends me an e-mail once a transaction has been completed. However, I would need the listener to send some sort of notification that an item (uniquely determined by an ID) has been sold, so that I can dynamically update my list of items available for sale.

Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: the ipn listener should update a db, then the item buy button would not appear, you don't want to be doing this by hand.

Comment: You can send custom data back to yourself (if needed) to uniquely identify the item(s). In your IPN listener, use the information that PayPal sends you to update your database. IPN callbacks aren't always instantaneous (might take a few seconds); if that matters, you may need an AJAX solution (perhaps long polling) to notify and update the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a qty_available field in your products database.  Then display only products where qty_available > 0 on the website.

When something sells update the qty_available in your database within your IPN script.  This way when something sells out it will no longer be displayed on the site.